# Translate My.Application.Deployment.ActivationUri to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

How do I translate My.Application.Deployment.ActivationUri into C#?

Comment: Not that the extra 15 points is the end of the world or anything but is there any reason you marked an answer as accepted that was literally the exact same thing I posted 7 minutes earlier?

Comment: Strange, when I looked at this last I could have sworn that the other person answered first. There was no other reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.ActivationUri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment.currentdeployment.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

[`ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment.currentdeployment.aspx) and further on.